# How to comment code that has a complicated explanation

Tags: comments

I have a `if (a > b) { ..` in my code, which I would like to explain why is there to someone looking at the code.

The reason for it being there is quite complicated and cannot be explained well without the use of images.

The question is, how to best document this to a programmer looking at the code? Is there a generally accepted way?

Should I create a comment in the code saying "See explanation XX", and then create a document somewhere containing XX?

Comment: Better names than `a` and `b` would be a good start :-)

Comment: Regarding the [on hold] state. I am asking for a general accepted way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes well. `a` could be called `DidTheQuantizationNoiseFailToBeBelowEpsilon`, but it seems a bit excessive for this kind of question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of this will depend on what you are coding and the size of your project, but generally I would say that you should comment this particular conditional with an explanation only for what `if (a > b) { ..` is checking for, and *why*.

When you get to the content inside the if condition, explain that. Broader explanations as to the purpose of the function itself and its objectives should generally be in the declaration, although you can also add descriptions to the definition (I prefer to avoid this generally, although I sometimes describe the method in further detail on top of the definition, where it would simply clutter the declaration of the class).

For example,

```
class A
{
// this method performs operations on x or y as appropriate, given the input conditions of
// a and b. Its purpose is ... and in order to achieve this it does ...
void Method(int a, int b);
};

// elsewhere in a .cpp file

// Note that this method uses method abc rather than method cde in order to achieve
// such and such more efficiently (description here is more technical than in the
// declaration, and might focus on more specific issues while still remaining 
// applicable to the function as a whole, and should therefore not be in the body)
void A::Method(int a, int b)
{
    // check to see whether or not a > b in order to decide whether to operate on x or on y
    if (a > b)
    {
      // a is greater than b, and therefore we need to operate on x because...
    }
    else
    {
      // a is not greater than b, therefore we need to operate on y because...
    }
}
```

I find that by structuring my comments to address the reason why specific sections of code are the way they are, the reader is able to "follow the story" that the code is telling as she reads through it.

If it is absolutely impossible to describe what the `if` section is doing without a broader explanation, then by all means add a paragraph or two. There is nothing wrong with long comments as long as they are well placed and address the specific purpose of the following lines of code. You shouldn't need to add *for more information, see function header* because that should already be implied.

You can add broader descriptions to the enclosing function, method, or scope, but comments should always address the piece of code they are referring to as succinctly as possible. After all, if the reader wanted to know what the whole function was doing, she'd look at the declaration. The reason she's looking at the definition of the function is because she wants to know what the *components* of the function are doing, and so the comments should address just that.